# Icons/images not loaded in IE after adding “X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff” in web.config file

Tags: asp.net, image, security, internet-explorer, web-config

I am using ASP.NET platform to create a web page. Inside the page i have used some images/icons. For security purpose i have used  “X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff” in web.config file. When i deploy the web page in IE, some of the images/icons isn't rendered. But, the same page working fine in Firefox and Chrome.

When i remove the statement “X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff” from web.config everything is working fine in IE. But, for security purpose i must use that statement. At the same time the missing images/icons need to be rendered in IE.

So, can anyone help me how to fix the issue with the statement “X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff".

Thanks in advance,

Comment: how are u adding that in the webconfig?

Comment: But, i found the extension and the image/icon type get mismatched while using the statement “X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff" that results the images/icons are not displayed in IE. Can anyone share why it is getting mismatched and provide solution to match the images/icons with exact extension.

Comment: This sounds similar to my problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49327387/asp-net-ajax-toolkit-slider-handle-displays-broken-image I'm having trouble with the ASP.NET Ajax toolkit slider where the slider handle image renders as a broken image when I have the X-Content-Type-Options="nosniff” in web.config.  When I remove it, the slider renders fine.  This is only in IE11 for me. I'd also like to have X-Content-Type-Options="nosniff”.  Have you discovered a solution?

Answer (score 1):

The nosniff only applies to "script" and "style" types. Also applying nosniff to images turned out to be incompatible with existing web sites.

So "X-Content-Type-Options nosniff" would bypass the problem for images and here comes the browser role which fail to render the image if the type mentioned by the server is not matching the real file extension.

Refer to:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Content-Type-Options.

and this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg622941(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

IE uses MIME information to determine how to handle files sent by a Web server. For example, when Windows Internet Explorer receives a .jpg file, the user sees the file in an Windows Internet Explorer window. The MIME Handling Restrictions feature helps prevent script injection attacks against Web servers by ensuring that any content delivered with an IMAGE MIME is not treated as HTML or XML.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/compatibility/dd565640(v=vs.85)

Answer (score 0):

Add following line before saving bitmap

```
Response.ContentType = "image/gif";
```